# Getting more information out of make file

Tags: c++, makefile, mingw

I am trying to build an external library called ACE

and I get this linker error

```
   admin@UKS03044 MSYS /c/ACE/ACE_wrappers/ace
$ mingw32-make.exe
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/ACE/ACE_wrappers/ace'

GNUmakefile: /c/ACE/ACE_wrappers/ace/GNUmakefile.ACE MAKEFLAGS=w

dlltool --dllname libACE.dll --output-lib libACE.dll.a .shobj/Local_Name_Space.o .shobj/Name_Proxy.o .shobj/Name_Request_Reply.o .shobj/Name_Space.o .shobj/Naming_Context.o .shobj/Registry_Name_Space.o .shobj/Remote_Name_Space.o .shobj/NT_Service.o .shobj/Codecs.o .shobj/Local_Tokens.o .shobj/Remote_Tokens.o .shobj/Token_Collection.o .shobj/Token_Invariants.o .shobj/Token_Manager.o .shobj/Token_Request_Reply.o .shobj/DLL.o .shobj/Dynamic_Service_Base.o .shobj/Dynamic_Service_Dependency.o .shobj/Parse_Node.o .shobj/Service_Config.o .shobj/Service_Gestalt.o .shobj/Service_Manager.o .shobj/Service_Object.o .shobj/Service_Repository.o .shobj/Service_Types.o .shobj/Shared_Object.o .shobj/Svc_Conf_Lexer.o .shobj/Svc_Conf_y.o .shobj/Encoding_Converter.o .shobj/Encoding_Converter_Factory.o .shobj/UTF8_Encoding_Converter.o .shobj/UTF16_Encoding_Converter.o .shobj/UTF32_Encoding_Converter.o .shobj/XML_Svc_Conf.o .shobj/UUID.o .shobj/Filecache.o .shobj/ACE.o .shobj/ACE_crc_ccitt.o .shobj/ACE_crc32.o .shobj/ace_wchar.o .shobj/Activation_Queue.o .shobj/Active_Map_Manager.o .shobj/Addr.o .shobj/Argv_Type_Converter.o .shobj/Assert.o .shobj/Asynch_IO.o .shobj/Asynch_IO_Impl.o .shobj/Asynch_Pseudo_Task.o .shobj/ATM_Acceptor.o .shobj/ATM_Addr.o .shobj/ATM_Connector.o .shobj/ATM_Params.o .shobj/ATM_QoS.o .shobj/ATM_Stream.o .shobj/Atomic_Op.o .shobj/Atomic_Op_Sparc.o .shobj/Barrier.o .shobj/Base_Thread_Adapter.o .shobj/Based_Pointer_Repository.o .shobj/Basic_Stats.o .shobj/Basic_Types.o .shobj/Capabilities.o .shobj/CDR_Base.o .shobj/CDR_Stream.o .shobj/CDR_Size.o .shobj/Cleanup.o .shobj/Codeset_IBM1047.o .shobj/Codeset_Registry.o .shobj/Codeset_Registry_db.o .shobj/Condition_Attributes.o .shobj/Condition_Recursive_Thread_Mutex.o .shobj/Condition_Thread_Mutex.o .shobj/Configuration.o .shobj/Configuration_Import_Export.o .shobj/Connection_Recycling_Strategy.o .shobj/Containers.o .shobj/Copy_Disabled.o .shobj/Date_Time.o .shobj/DEV.o .shobj/DEV_Addr.o .shobj/DEV_Connector.o .shobj/DEV_IO.o .shobj/DLL_Manager.o .shobj/Dev_Poll_Reactor.o .shobj/Dirent.o .shobj/Dirent_Selector.o .shobj/Dump.o .shobj/Dynamic.o .shobj/Dynamic_Message_Strategy.o .shobj/Event_Base.o .shobj/Event_Handler.o .shobj/Event_Handler_Handle_Timeout_Upcall.o .shobj/FIFO.o .shobj/FIFO_Recv.o .shobj/FIFO_Recv_Msg.o .shobj/FIFO_Send.o .shobj/FIFO_Send_Msg.o .shobj/FILE.o .shobj/FILE_Addr.o .shobj/FILE_Connector.o .shobj/FILE_IO.o .shobj/File_Lock.o .shobj/Flag_Manip.o .shobj/Framework_Component.o .shobj/Functor.o .shobj/Functor_String.o .shobj/Get_Opt.o .shobj/Handle_Ops.o .shobj/Handle_Set.o .shobj/Hashable.o .shobj/High_Res_Timer.o .shobj/ICMP_Socket.o .shobj/INET_Addr.o .shobj/Init_ACE.o .shobj/IO_SAP.o .shobj/IO_Cntl_Msg.o .shobj/IOStream.o .shobj/IPC_SAP.o .shobj/Lib_Find.o .shobj/Local_Memory_Pool.o .shobj/Lock.o .shobj/Log_Category.o .shobj/Log_Msg.o .shobj/Log_Msg_Backend.o .shobj/Log_Msg_Callback.o .shobj/Log_Msg_IPC.o .shobj/Log_Msg_NT_Event_Log.o .shobj/Log_Msg_UNIX_Syslog.o .shobj/Log_Record.o .shobj/Logging_Strategy.o .shobj/LSOCK.o .shobj/LSOCK_Acceptor.o .shobj/LSOCK_CODgram.o .shobj/LSOCK_Connector.o .shobj/LSOCK_Dgram.o .shobj/LSOCK_Stream.o .shobj/Malloc.o .shobj/Malloc_Allocator.o .shobj/MEM_Acceptor.o .shobj/MEM_Addr.o .shobj/MEM_Connector.o .shobj/MEM_IO.o .shobj/Mem_Map.o .shobj/MEM_SAP.o .shobj/MEM_Stream.o .shobj/Message_Block.o .shobj/Message_Queue.o .shobj/Message_Queue_NT.o .shobj/Message_Queue_Vx.o .shobj/Method_Request.o .shobj/MMAP_Memory_Pool.o .shobj/Msg_WFMO_Reactor.o .shobj/Monitor_Admin.o .shobj/Monitor_Admin_Manager.o .shobj/Monitor_Base.o .shobj/Monitor_Point_Registry.o .shobj/Monitor_Size.o .shobj/Monitor_Control_Types.o .shobj/Monitor_Control_Action.o .shobj/Monotonic_Time_Policy.o .shobj/Multihomed_INET_Addr.o .shobj/Mutex.o .shobj/Netlink_Addr.o .shobj/Notification_Strategy.o .shobj/Notification_Queue.o .shobj/Obchunk.o .shobj/Object_Manager.o .shobj/Object_Manager_Base.o .shobj/Obstack.o .shobj/OS_Errno.o .shobj/OS_Log_Msg_Attributes.o .shobj/OS_main.o .shobj/OS_NS_arpa_inet.o .shobj/OS_NS_ctype.o .shobj/OS_NS_dirent.o .shobj/OS_NS_dlfcn.o .shobj/OS_NS_errno.o .shobj/OS_NS_fcntl.o .shobj/OS_NS_math.o .shobj/OS_NS_netdb.o .shobj/OS_NS_poll.o .shobj/OS_NS_pwd.o .shobj/OS_NS_regex.o .shobj/OS_NS_signal.o .shobj/OS_NS_stdio.o .shobj/OS_NS_stdlib.o .shobj/OS_NS_string.o .shobj/OS_NS_strings.o .shobj/OS_NS_stropts.o .shobj/OS_NS_sys_mman.o .shobj/OS_NS_sys_msg.o .shobj/OS_NS_sys_resource.o .shobj/OS_NS_sys_select.o .shobj/OS_NS_sys_sendfile.o .shobj/OS_NS_sys_shm.o .shobj/OS_NS_sys_socket.o .shobj/OS_NS_sys_stat.o .shobj/OS_NS_sys_time.o .shobj/OS_NS_sys_uio.o .shobj/OS_NS_sys_utsname.o .shobj/OS_NS_sys_wait.o .shobj/OS_NS_Thread.o .shobj/OS_NS_time.o .shobj/OS_NS_unistd.o .shobj/OS_NS_wchar.o .shobj/OS_NS_wctype.o .shobj/OS_QoS.o .shobj/OS_Thread_Adapter.o .shobj/OS_TLI.o .shobj/Pagefile_Memory_Pool.o .shobj/PI_Malloc.o .shobj/Ping_Socket.o .shobj/Pipe.o .shobj/POSIX_Asynch_IO.o .shobj/POSIX_CB_Proactor.o .shobj/POSIX_Proactor.o .shobj/Priority_Reactor.o .shobj/Proactor.o .shobj/Proactor_Impl.o .shobj/Process.o .shobj/Process_Manager.o .shobj/Process_Mutex.o .shobj/Process_Semaphore.o .shobj/Profile_Timer.o .shobj/Reactor.o .shobj/Reactor_Impl.o .shobj/Reactor_Notification_Strategy.o .shobj/Reactor_Timer_Interface.o .shobj/Read_Buffer.o .shobj/Recursive_Thread_Mutex.o .shobj/Recyclable.o .shobj/Registry.o .shobj/Rtems_init.o .shobj/RW_Mutex.o .shobj/RW_Process_Mutex.o .shobj/RW_Thread_Mutex.o .shobj/Sample_History.o .shobj/Sbrk_Memory_Pool.o .shobj/Sched_Params.o .shobj/Select_Reactor_Base.o .shobj/Semaphore.o .shobj/Shared_Memory.o .shobj/Shared_Memory_MM.o .shobj/Shared_Memory_Pool.o .shobj/Shared_Memory_SV.o .shobj/Sig_Adapter.o .shobj/Sig_Handler.o .shobj/Signal.o .shobj/SOCK.o .shobj/SOCK_Acceptor.o .shobj/SOCK_CODgram.o .shobj/Sock_Connect.o .shobj/SOCK_Connector.o .shobj/SOCK_Dgram.o .shobj/SOCK_Dgram_Bcast.o .shobj/SOCK_Dgram_Mcast.o .shobj/SOCK_IO.o .shobj/SOCK_Netlink.o .shobj/SOCK_SEQPACK_Acceptor.o .shobj/SOCK_SEQPACK_Association.o .shobj/SOCK_SEQPACK_Connector.o .shobj/SOCK_Stream.o .shobj/SPIPE.o .shobj/SPIPE_Acceptor.o .shobj/SPIPE_Addr.o .shobj/SPIPE_Connector.o .shobj/SPIPE_Stream.o .shobj/SString.o .shobj/Stack_Trace.o .shobj/Stats.o .shobj/String_Base_Const.o .shobj/SUN_Proactor.o .shobj/SV_Message.o .shobj/SV_Message_Queue.o .shobj/SV_Semaphore_Complex.o .shobj/SV_Semaphore_Simple.o .shobj/SV_Shared_Memory.o .shobj/Synch_Options.o .shobj/System_Time.o .shobj/Task.o .shobj/Thread.o .shobj/Thread_Adapter.o .shobj/Thread_Control.o .shobj/Thread_Exit.o .shobj/Thread_Hook.o .shobj/Thread_Manager.o .shobj/Thread_Mutex.o .shobj/Thread_Semaphore.o .shobj/Throughput_Stats.o .shobj/Time_Policy.o .shobj/Time_Value.o .shobj/Timeprobe.o .shobj/TLI.o .shobj/TLI_Acceptor.o .shobj/TLI_Connector.o .shobj/TLI_Stream.o .shobj/Token.o .shobj/TP_Reactor.o .shobj/Trace.o .shobj/TSS_Adapter.o .shobj/TTY_IO.o .shobj/UNIX_Addr.o .shobj/UPIPE_Acceptor.o .shobj/UPIPE_Connector.o .shobj/UPIPE_Stream.o .shobj/WFMO_Reactor.o .shobj/WIN32_Asynch_IO.o .shobj/WIN32_Proactor.o .shobj/XTI_ATM_Mcast.o .shobj/ace.rc.o &&  g++  -Wl,--enable-auto-image-base -Wl,--out-implib,libACE.dll.a -shared -o libACE.dll -Wl,--enable-auto-import -L../lib -L.  -L../lib  .shobj/Local_Name_Space.o .shobj/Name_Proxy.o .shobj/Name_Request_Reply.o .shobj/Name_Space.o .shobj/Naming_Context.o .shobj/Registry_Name_Space.o .shobj/Remote_Name_Space.o .shobj/NT_Service.o .shobj/Codecs.o .shobj/Local_Tokens.o .shobj/Remote_Tokens.o .shobj/Token_Collection.o .shobj/Token_Invariants.o .shobj/Token_Manager.o .shobj/Token_Request_Reply.o .shobj/DLL.o .shobj/Dynamic_Service_Base.o .shobj/Dynamic_Service_Dependency.o .shobj/Parse_Node.o .shobj/Service_Config.o .shobj/Service_Gestalt.o .shobj/Service_Manager.o .shobj/Service_Object.o .shobj/Service_Repository.o .shobj/Service_Types.o .shobj/Shared_Object.o .shobj/Svc_Conf_Lexer.o .shobj/Svc_Conf_y.o .shobj/Encoding_Converter.o .shobj/Encoding_Converter_Factory.o .shobj/UTF8_Encoding_Converter.o .shobj/UTF16_Encoding_Converter.o .shobj/UTF32_Encoding_Converter.o .shobj/XML_Svc_Conf.o .shobj/UUID.o .shobj/Filecache.o .shobj/ACE.o .shobj/ACE_crc_ccitt.o .shobj/ACE_crc32.o .shobj/ace_wchar.o .shobj/Activation_Queue.o .shobj/Active_Map_Manager.o .shobj/Addr.o .shobj/Argv_Type_Converter.o .shobj/Assert.o .shobj/Asynch_IO.o .shobj/Asynch_IO_Impl.o .shobj/Asynch_Pseudo_Task.o .shobj/ATM_Acceptor.o .shobj/ATM_Addr.o .shobj/ATM_Connector.o .shobj/ATM_Params.o .shobj/ATM_QoS.o .shobj/ATM_Stream.o .shobj/Atomic_Op.o .shobj/Atomic_Op_Sparc.o .shobj/Barrier.o .shobj/Base_Thread_Adapter.o .shobj/Based_Pointer_Repository.o .shobj/Basic_Stats.o .shobj/Basic_Types.o .shobj/Capabilities.o .shobj/CDR_Base.o .shobj/CDR_Stream.o .shobj/CDR_Size.o .shobj/Cleanup.o .shobj/Codeset_IBM1047.o .shobj/Codeset_Registry.o .shobj/Codeset_Registry_db.o .shobj/Condition_Attributes.o .shobj/Condition_Recursive_Thread_Mutex.o .shobj/Condition_Thread_Mutex.o .shobj/Configuration.o .shobj/Configuration_Import_Export.o .shobj/Connection_Recycling_Strategy.o .shobj/Containers.o .shobj/Copy_Disabled.o .shobj/Date_Time.o .shobj/DEV.o .shobj/DEV_Addr.o .shobj/DEV_Connector.o .shobj/DEV_IO.o .shobj/DLL_Manager.o .shobj/Dev_Poll_Reactor.o .shobj/Dirent.o .shobj/Dirent_Selector.o .shobj/Dump.o .shobj/Dynamic.o .shobj/Dynamic_Message_Strategy.o .shobj/Event_Base.o .shobj/Event_Handler.o .shobj/Event_Handler_Handle_Timeout_Upcall.o .shobj/FIFO.o .shobj/FIFO_Recv.o .shobj/FIFO_Recv_Msg.o .shobj/FIFO_Send.o .shobj/FIFO_Send_Msg.o .shobj/FILE.o .shobj/FILE_Addr.o .shobj/FILE_Connector.o .shobj/FILE_IO.o .shobj/File_Lock.o .shobj/Flag_Manip.o .shobj/Framework_Component.o .shobj/Functor.o .shobj/Functor_String.o .shobj/Get_Opt.o .shobj/Handle_Ops.o .shobj/Handle_Set.o .shobj/Hashable.o .shobj/High_Res_Timer.o .shobj/ICMP_Socket.o .shobj/INET_Addr.o .shobj/Init_ACE.o .shobj/IO_SAP.o .shobj/IO_Cntl_Msg.o .shobj/IOStream.o .shobj/IPC_SAP.o .shobj/Lib_Find.o .shobj/Local_Memory_Pool.o .shobj/Lock.o .shobj/Log_Category.o .shobj/Log_Msg.o .shobj/Log_Msg_Backend.o .shobj/Log_Msg_Callback.o .shobj/Log_Msg_IPC.o .shobj/Log_Msg_NT_Event_Log.o .shobj/Log_Msg_UNIX_Syslog.o .shobj/Log_Record.o .shobj/Logging_Strategy.o .shobj/LSOCK.o .shobj/LSOCK_Acceptor.o .shobj/LSOCK_CODgram.o .shobj/LSOCK_Connector.o .shobj/LSOCK_Dgram.o .shobj/LSOCK_Stream.o .shobj/Malloc.o .shobj/Malloc_Allocator.o .shobj/MEM_Acceptor.o .shobj/MEM_Addr.o .shobj/MEM_Connector.o .shobj/MEM_IO.o .shobj/Mem_Map.o .shobj/MEM_SAP.o .shobj/MEM_Stream.o .shobj/Message_Block.o .shobj/Message_Queue.o .shobj/Message_Queue_NT.o .shobj/Message_Queue_Vx.o .shobj/Method_Request.o .shobj/MMAP_Memory_Pool.o .shobj/Msg_WFMO_Reactor.o .shobj/Monitor_Admin.o .shobj/Monitor_Admin_Manager.o .shobj/Monitor_Base.o .shobj/Monitor_Point_Registry.o .shobj/Monitor_Size.o .shobj/Monitor_Control_Types.o .shobj/Monitor_Control_Action.o .shobj/Monotonic_Time_Policy.o .shobj/Multihomed_INET_Addr.o .shobj/Mutex.o .shobj/Netlink_Addr.o .shobj/Notification_Strategy.o .shobj/Notification_Queue.o .shobj/Obchunk.o .shobj/Object_Manager.o .shobj/Object_Manager_Base.o .shobj/Obstack.o .shobj/OS_Errno.o .shobj/OS_Log_Msg_Attributes.o .shobj/OS_main.o .shobj/OS_NS_arpa_inet.o .shobj/OS_NS_ctype.o .shobj/OS_NS_dirent.o .shobj/OS_NS_dlfcn.o .shobj/OS_NS_errno.o .shobj/OS_NS_fcntl.o .shobj/OS_NS_math.o .shobj/OS_NS_netdb.o .shobj/OS_NS_poll.o .shobj/OS_NS_pwd.o .shobj/OS_NS_regex.o .shobj/OS_NS_signal.o .shobj/OS_NS_stdio.o .shobj/OS_NS_stdlib.o .shobj/OS_NS_string.o .shobj/OS_NS_strings.o .shobj/OS_NS_stropts.o .shobj/OS_NS_sys_mman.o .shobj/OS_NS_sys_msg.o .shobj/OS_NS_sys_resource.o .shobj/OS_NS_sys_select.o .shobj/OS_NS_sys_sendfile.o .shobj/OS_NS_sys_shm.o .shobj/OS_NS_sys_socket.o .shobj/OS_NS_sys_stat.o .shobj/OS_NS_sys_time.o .shobj/OS_NS_sys_uio.o .shobj/OS_NS_sys_utsname.o .shobj/OS_NS_sys_wait.o .shobj/OS_NS_Thread.o .shobj/OS_NS_time.o .shobj/OS_NS_unistd.o .shobj/OS_NS_wchar.o .shobj/OS_NS_wctype.o .shobj/OS_QoS.o .shobj/OS_Thread_Adapter.o .shobj/OS_TLI.o .shobj/Pagefile_Memory_Pool.o .shobj/PI_Malloc.o .shobj/Ping_Socket.o .shobj/Pipe.o .shobj/POSIX_Asynch_IO.o .shobj/POSIX_CB_Proactor.o .shobj/POSIX_Proactor.o .shobj/Priority_Reactor.o .shobj/Proactor.o .shobj/Proactor_Impl.o .shobj/Process.o .shobj/Process_Manager.o .shobj/Process_Mutex.o .shobj/Process_Semaphore.o .shobj/Profile_Timer.o .shobj/Reactor.o .shobj/Reactor_Impl.o .shobj/Reactor_Notification_Strategy.o .shobj/Reactor_Timer_Interface.o .shobj/Read_Buffer.o .shobj/Recursive_Thread_Mutex.o .shobj/Recyclable.o .shobj/Registry.o .shobj/Rtems_init.o .shobj/RW_Mutex.o .shobj/RW_Process_Mutex.o .shobj/RW_Thread_Mutex.o .shobj/Sample_History.o .shobj/Sbrk_Memory_Pool.o .shobj/Sched_Params.o .shobj/Select_Reactor_Base.o .shobj/Semaphore.o .shobj/Shared_Memory.o .shobj/Shared_Memory_MM.o .shobj/Shared_Memory_Pool.o .shobj/Shared_Memory_SV.o .shobj/Sig_Adapter.o .shobj/Sig_Handler.o .shobj/Signal.o .shobj/SOCK.o .shobj/SOCK_Acceptor.o .shobj/SOCK_CODgram.o .shobj/Sock_Connect.o .shobj/SOCK_Connector.o .shobj/SOCK_Dgram.o .shobj/SOCK_Dgram_Bcast.o .shobj/SOCK_Dgram_Mcast.o .shobj/SOCK_IO.o .shobj/SOCK_Netlink.o .shobj/SOCK_SEQPACK_Acceptor.o .shobj/SOCK_SEQPACK_Association.o .shobj/SOCK_SEQPACK_Connector.o .shobj/SOCK_Stream.o .shobj/SPIPE.o .shobj/SPIPE_Acceptor.o .shobj/SPIPE_Addr.o .shobj/SPIPE_Connector.o .shobj/SPIPE_Stream.o .shobj/SString.o .shobj/Stack_Trace.o .shobj/Stats.o .shobj/String_Base_Const.o .shobj/SUN_Proactor.o .shobj/SV_Message.o .shobj/SV_Message_Queue.o .shobj/SV_Semaphore_Complex.o .shobj/SV_Semaphore_Simple.o .shobj/SV_Shared_Memory.o .shobj/Synch_Options.o .shobj/System_Time.o .shobj/Task.o .shobj/Thread.o .shobj/Thread_Adapter.o .shobj/Thread_Control.o .shobj/Thread_Exit.o .shobj/Thread_Hook.o .shobj/Thread_Manager.o .shobj/Thread_Mutex.o .shobj/Thread_Semaphore.o .shobj/Throughput_Stats.o .shobj/Time_Policy.o .shobj/Time_Value.o .shobj/Timeprobe.o .shobj/TLI.o .shobj/TLI_Acceptor.o .shobj/TLI_Connector.o .shobj/TLI_Stream.o .shobj/Token.o .shobj/TP_Reactor.o .shobj/Trace.o .shobj/TSS_Adapter.o .shobj/TTY_IO.o .shobj/UNIX_Addr.o .shobj/UPIPE_Acceptor.o .shobj/UPIPE_Connector.o .shobj/UPIPE_Stream.o .shobj/WFMO_Reactor.o .shobj/WIN32_Asynch_IO.o .shobj/WIN32_Proactor.o .shobj/XTI_ATM_Mcast.o .shobj/ace.rc.o  -lws2_32 -lmswsock -liphlpapi -lwsock32 -lnetapi32
C:/nmingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find .: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
C:/ACE/ACE_wrappers/include/makeinclude/rules.lib.GNU:242: recipe for target 'libACE.dll' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [libACE.dll] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/ACE/ACE_wrappers/ace'
GNUmakefile:45: recipe for target 'ACE' failed
mingw32-make: *** [ACE] Error 2
```

I am not sure what the issue is here

```
ld.exe cannot find .: Permission denied
```

Any suggestions on how to get a more detailed message with Make ?

Comment: What is the rest of the command that you chopped at the top of that output? That should be a call to `ld` or something that calls `ld` and it should have a bare `.` in it somewhere in the argument list which is the problem. The makefile, for some reason, would seem to be including a bare `.` in the arguments to `ld`.

Comment: Ill add the remaining item

Comment: Just updated the post

Comment: The error might be the `-L.` argument but I would have expected that to work correctly even on Windows (though anything is possible). It could also be a permissions issue on the directory (though I think that is probably unlikely). I'm not sure what to suggest at this point though. You could try to find out where that `-L.` argument is coming from and seeing if you can remove it (assuming things will work correctly without it).

Answer (score 0):

In order to resolve this issue I needed to install msys2 and then add the development packages to it using

```
 pacman -S --needed base-devel
```

The above command adds the make tool to msys. So instead of using the make tool present in my mingw directory i needed to use the make tool installed by the above command.